# PowerShell Enum Evaluation

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to write a script to deploy permissions to an Azure Data Lake. I want to test for the existing permissions before I add more but am coming undone at working with a Enum.

The script to get the permissions is:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'mylake' -UseConnectedAccount
$FilesystemName = "lake"
$path = "folder"
$acl = (Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $FileSystemName -Path $Path).ACL
```

$acl is now an array of PSPathAccessControlEntry.
If I run `$acl[0].Permissions.GetType()` I get:

> Name: RolePermissions 
> BaseType: System.Enum

`$acl[0].Permissions` returns:

> Execute, Read

I want to test if the enum contains "Read". But I can't find any methods to evaluate it. I've found plenty of posts about creating new enums and working with them, but can't find anything around working with enums in imported modules (that you have not declared)

For example, things like  `[enum]::GetNames([RolePermissions])` will not work because it cannot find that name, is there another way to reference it?

Comment: `if ($acl[0].Permissions -band 4)`. Read equals 4, see [RolePermissions enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.models.rolepermissions?view=azure-dotnet). I cannot test, but this should also work: `if ($acl[0].Permissions -band [Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.Models.RolePermissions]::Read)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `RolePermissions` value like the one you describe:

```
using namespace Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.Models
$Permissions = [RolePermissions]'Execute, Read'
```

... there are two ways of assessing whether the `$Permissions` value has the `Read` flag:

### Using `Enum.HasFlag()`

We can do:

```
PS ~> $Permissions.HasFlag([RolePermissions]::Read)
True
```

### Doing the math

Since enum flags are combined using bitwise arithmetic, we can use bitwise operators to interrogate them:

```
PS ~> ($Permissions -band [RolePermissions]::Read) -eq [RolePermissions]::Read
True
```

Like any other overloaded binary operator in PowerShell, `-band` defaults to the type of the left-hand side argument, so we can pass just the label name:

```
PS ~> ($Permissions -band 'Read') -eq 'Read'
True
```